# Registration with .NET Core Identity name field error - "User name '' is invalid, can only contain letters or digits."

Tags: c#, html, entity-framework, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I have created a registration form with ASP.NET Core Identity, using the default fields ("Email", "Password", "Confirm Password") and a custom field "Name". When I enter a random string value into the name field and press "Register", I always receive the below error message:

"User name '' is invalid, can only contain letters or digits."

Things I have tried:

- I have set an option on the 'User' object for AllowedUserNameCharacters, but this doesn't seem to make a difference:

```
    services.Configure<IdentityOptions>(options =>
                {
                    options.User.AllowedUserNameCharacters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789-._@+";
    }
```

My registration controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var user = new ApplicationUser
            {
                Name = model.Name,                    
                Email = model.Email
            };  
    
            var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
    
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                await _signInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false);
    
                return RedirectToAction("index", "Home");
            }
    
            foreach (var error in result.Errors)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", error.Description);
            }
    
            ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Invalid Login Attempt");
        }
    
        return View(model);
    }
```

Regsitration View:

```
    <form method="post">
                <div asp-validation-summary="All" class="text-danger"></div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="Name"></label>
                    <input asp-for="Name" class="form-control" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="Name" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
    
    
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="Email"></label>
                    <input asp-for="Email" class="form-control" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="Email" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
    
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="Password"></label>
                    <input asp-for="Password" class="form-control" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="Password" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
    
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="ConfirmPassword"></label>
                    <input asp-for="ConfirmPassword" class="form-control" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="ConfirmPassword" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn-primary">Register</button>
    
    
            </form>
```

```
My appDBContext:

    public class AppDBContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
    {
        private readonly DbContextOptions _options;

        public AppDBContext()
        {

        }

        public AppDBContext(DbContextOptions options): base(options)
        {
            _options = options;
        }

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            if (!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured)
            {
                optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(
                @"Server=(localdb)\mssqllocaldb;Database=Codefirst");
            }
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

            modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>()
            .Property(e => e.Name)
            .HasMaxLength(250);

            modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>()
            .Property(e => e.Email)
            .HasMaxLength(250);
        }
    }
```

```
My applicationuser.cs class:
```

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;

namespace SLE_System.Data
{
    public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public string Email { get; set; }

        public string Password { get; set; }

        public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
    }
}
```

```
If anyone has any ideas, these would be much appreciated?

Thanks,

Robert
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`"UserName" is invalid, can only contain letters or digits.` is the default error message  about `UserName` property. In your Regsitration View, There is no input for `UserName`, So when you use `CreateAsync()` method to register user, The project will validate your properties and find `UserName` property is null and return this error message.

So one simply method is give it a value when you register ApplicationUser.

```
[HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var user = new ApplicationUser
            {
                Name = model.Name,
                UserName = model.Name,                    
                Email = model.Email
            };  
            //.......
```

But please note that when you input `Name` property, You need to satisfy `UserName`'s validation rules. The default rule is to only support the following characters

```
"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789-._@+"
```

You can also custom it's validation rule by using:

```
services.Configure<IdentityOptions>(options =>
                {
                    options.User.AllowedUserNameCharacters = "xxxxxx";
                    //..............
```

Answer (score 1):

**Here IdentiyUser Class is inherited**

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
}
```

And the IdentityUser class has following properties as per Microsoft documentation [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.entityframeworkcore.identityuser?view=aspnetcore-1.1)
there is property UserName which is also inherited.

**By default string(Non Nullable Properties) datatype have default data annotation [Required("AllowEmptyStrings"=true)].Since while send the registered data UserName is missing but it is required so it is throwing error.**